# Android Development: Screen fit in different devices

Tags: android, screen, resolution

I got a HTC Desire and a HTC Sensation. My applications do fit perfect for the Desire but when i run them with my qHD Sensation the application gets really small on the device. And the rest is just blank(black color)

How do i fix this?

//Simon

Comment: Could you post a .XML file for one of the layouts that doesn't fill the Sensation screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using device-independent pixels in your layout (use the unit "dp" instead of "px" in your XML and code).

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Edit:

Marakana has a pretty good video tutorial series that covers device-independent pixels and "proper" Android UI design: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lESZqCflB0o

Comment: Thank but i don't understand that much of it.

Comment: Not so sure that dp versus px will help in this particular instance.  I'm pretty sure both the Sensation and the Desire are normal-hdpi devices, and so dp values will work out to the same number of physical pixels on both screens.  I suspect the problem is that the OP is using hardcoded pixel values when he shouldn't be specifying them at all.  Ideally he should just let Android dynamically place the widgets to fill the space.

Comment: Answer updated. I would strongly suggest watching some of the Marakana tutorial series on YouTube, it really helped me understand the UI dev process.

Comment: Yes but i have my LinearLayout set to Fill_parent

Comment: I think it would be helpful at this point to post some of the offending code in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

change the `<uses-sdk.../>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to the following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

worked for me :)